# Why is (g) not $Ax=b$ has and only has one solution for each b in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Theorem 8**
>
> Let $A$ be a square $n\times n$ matrix. Then the following statements are equivalent. That is, for a given $A$, the statements are either all true or all false.
>
> a. $A$ is an invertable matrix.
>
> b. $A$ is row equivalent to the $n\times n$ identity matrix.
>
> c. $A$ has $n$ pivot points.
>
> d. The equation $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution.
>
> e. The columns of $A$ for a linearly idependent set.
>
> f. The linear transformation $x\mapsto Ax$ is one-to-one.
>
> g. The equation $Ax=b$ has at least one solution for each $b$ in $\Bbb R^n$.
>
> h. The columns of $A$ span $\Bbb R^n$.
>
> i. The linear transformation $x\mapsto Ax$ maps $\Bbb R^n$ onto $\Bbb R^n$.
>
> j. There is an $n\times n$ matrix $C$ such that $CA=I$.
>
> k. There is an $n\times n$ matrix $D$ such that $AD=I$.
>
> l. $A^T$ is an invertable matrix.

Why is it "The equation $Ax=b$ has at least one solution for each b in $\mathbb R^n$" and not "The equation $Ax=b$ has one solution for each b in $\mathbb R^n$".

I think when $A$ is invertible, $Ax=b$ has and only has one solution for each $b$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

This comes from David C.lay's book called [Linear Algebra and its Applications](https://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_Algebra_and_Its_Applications.html?id=bM6gBwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description).

Comment: You can add that as another letter.  Having at least one solution for each $b$ and having exactly one solution for each $b$ are equivalent statements for an invertible matrix.  Why did they write it that way?  I don't know, but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: You can even write it afterwards (without the equivalence) more clearly yourself: " The equation $Ax=b$ *then* has exactly one solution for each $b$, namely $x=A^{-1}b$." And please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: They likely chose the weaker statement, because it yields a test that is easier to verify.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that is arguable.  I would write that as an afterthought as a corollary and not write $A^{-1}$ before having proven the equivalence of the statements.  Before having proved that (g) really is equivalent to (a) we wouldn't have reason to believe that $A^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: The point of Lay's "invertible matrix theorem" is to give you a whole bunch of statements that are equivalent for a square matrix, some of them "strong" and thus useful to invoke in a proof, and some of them "weak" and thus easy to check in a proof. That connection between ostensibly weak and strong statements is basically why the theorem is useful at all. Part (g) is one of the weak ones.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, you are right. The clarification is for the statement afterwards, when you know that $A$ is invertible. This is also a reason, perhaps, for the question itself, by the OP. *If* $A$ is invertible, we would rather say exactly one solution.

Comment: Note that point (d) says that for one particular $b$ (namely $b = 0$), there is _exactly one_ solution.